# イベントハンドラの削除方法

Tags: c#, visual-studio

こちらを参考にイベントハンドラの削除を実装してみたのですが
上手くいきません。
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/yuta-celestial/20071008/1191854503

```
    private void listView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

            this.listView1.MouseUp -= new System.EventHandler(listView1_MouseUp);
    }
```

デリゲート 'EventHandler' に一致する 'listView1_MouseUp' のオーバーロードはありません

どのように対処すれば良いのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

visual studio express 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MouseUp`イベントは`MouseEventHandler`型ですので、

```
this.listView1.MouseUp -= new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(listView1_MouseUp);
```

が正しいです。

またデリゲート型のコンストラクターは省略できるので

```
this.listView1.MouseUp -= listView1_MouseUp;
```

とも書けます。